# unresolved external symbol problems?

Tags: c++

So first time posting and real beginner so hope doing this right but really need help with this program.

Thanks guys for all the help, I have made some changes and those errors have gone away, but now I am getting these:

Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl searchID(struct StudentRecord *,int)" (?searchID@@YAXPAUStudentRecord@@H@Z) referenced in function _main

Error   6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl sortRecordsByName(struct StudentRecord *,int)" (?sortRecordsByName@@YAXPAUStudentRecord@@H@Z) referenced in function _main

Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl getInformation(struct StudentRecord * const,int)" (?getInformation@@YAXQAUStudentRecord@@H@Z) referenced in function _main

Error   8   error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals

Here is the revised code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_SIZE = 20;

struct Answers
{
    char answer1;
    char answer2;
    char answer3;
    char answer4;
    char answer5;
};

struct StudentRecord
{
    int ID;
    char student_name[MAX_SIZE];
    Answers answer;
    double score;
    double average;
    char letter_grade;
};

void getInformation(StudentRecord student[], int&);
void enterKey(char[]);
void calculateAvgAndLetter(StudentRecord *student, int, char[]);
void sortRecordsByName(StudentRecord * student, int);
void displayResults(StudentRecord * student, int);
bool displayReport(StudentRecord * student, int);
void searchID(StudentRecord * student, int);




int main()
{
    int search;
    int ID = 0;
    bool check = false;
    char repeat = 'y';

    const int MAX_STUDENTS = 10;
    int number_of_students = 0;
    char key[5];

    do {
        cout << "How many students: ";
        cin >> number_of_students;

        StudentRecord student[MAX_STUDENTS];
        enterKey(key);
        getInformation(student,number_of_students);
        calculateAvgAndLetter(student, number_of_students, key);
        sortRecordsByName(student, number_of_students);
        displayResults(student, number_of_students);

        cout << "Would you like to search for a student (y for yes and n for no)?: ";
        cin >> search;

        while (search != 'n' && search != 'y') 
        {
            cout << "Wrong ID" << endl;
            cout << "Would you like to search for another student (y for yes and n for no)?: ";
            cin >> search; 
        }

        if (search == 'y') 
        {
            searchID(student, number_of_students);
            check = true; 
        }
        else
            check = false;


        while (check)
        {
            cout << "Would you like to search for another student (y for yes and n for no)?: ";
            cin >> search;

            while (search != 'n' && search != 'y') 
            {
                cout << "Wrong ID" << endl;
                cout << "Would you like to search for another student (y for yes and n for no)?: ";
                cin >> search; 
            }

            if (search == 'y')
            {
                searchID(student, number_of_students);
                check = true;
            }
            else
                check = false;

        }

        cout << "Would you like to process another group of students(y for yes and n for no)?: " << endl;
        cin >> repeat;

    } while (repeat == 'y');

    return 0;
}

void enterKey(char key[5])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        cout << "Please enter the answer to question " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> key[i]; }
}

void getInformation(StudentRecord *student[],int number_of_students)
{
    int max_students;
    char again;
    int i = 0;

    cout << "Would you like to enter student information? " << endl;
    cin >> again;

    if (again == 'Y' || again == 'y')
    {
        do
        {
            cout << "Please enter student " << i + 1 << " information:" << endl;
            cout << "Please Enter Student Name Last name first with no spaces: " << endl;
            cin >> student[i]->student_name;
            cout << "Please Enter Student Id Number: " << endl;
            cin >> student[i]->ID;

            cout << "Please enter the student's answer to question 1: ";
            cin >> student[i]->answer.answer1;
            cout << "Please enter the student's answer to question 2: ";
            cin >> student[i]->answer.answer2;
            cout << "Please enter the student's answer to question 3: ";
            cin >> student[i]->answer.answer3;
            cout << "Please enter the student's answer to question 4: ";
            cin >> student[i]->answer.answer4;
            cout << "Please enter the student's answer to question 5: ";
            cin >> student[i]->answer.answer5;
            i++;

            if (i < number_of_students) {
                cout << "Would you like to enter student information? " << endl;
                cin >> again;
            }
            else again='n';
        }

        while(again == 'y' || again == 'Y');
        cout<<"Reports:"<<endl;
    }
}

void sortByID(StudentRecord student[], int number_of_students)
{
    bool swap = true;
    int j = 0;
    int temp;

    while (swap) 
    {
        swap = false;
        j++;

        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_students - j; i++)
        {
            if (student[i].ID > student[i + 1].ID) 
            {
                temp = student[i].ID;
                student[i].ID = student[i + 1].ID;
                student[i + 1].ID = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

int LinearSearch(StudentRecord student[], int number_of_students, int ID, int first, int last)
{
    int i = 0;
    int position;

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++) 
    {

        if (ID == student[i].ID) {
            position = i; }
    }

    return position;
}

void SortRecordsByName(StudentRecord student[], int number_of_students)
{
    bool swap = true;
    int j = 0;
    StudentRecord temp;

    while (swap) 
    {
        swap = false;
        j++;
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_students - j; i++) 
        {
            if (student[i].student_name > student[i + 1].student_name) 
            {
                strcpy(temp.student_name,student[i].student_name);
                strcpy(student[i].student_name,student[i + 1].student_name);
                strcpy(student[i + 1].student_name,temp.student_name);
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

void calculateAvgAndLetter(StudentRecord student[], int number_of_students, char key[5])
{
    int points1;
    int points2;
    int points3;
    int points4;
    int points5;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++) 
    {
        if (student[i].answer.answer1 == key[0])
            points1 = 10;
        else
            points1 = 0;

        if (student[i].answer.answer2 == key[1])
            points2 = 10;
        else
            points2 = 0;

        if (student[i].answer.answer3 == key[2])
            points3 = 10;
        else
            points3=0;

        if (student[i].answer.answer4 == key[3])
            points4 = 10;
        else
            points4 = 0;

        if (student[i].answer.answer5 == key[4])
            points5 = 10;
        else
            points5 = 0;

        student[i].score= points1 + points2 + points3 + points4 + points5;
        student[i].average = student[i].score * 2 ;


        if((student[i].average >= 90) && (student[i].average <= 100))
            student[i].letter_grade='A';

        else if ((student[i].average >= 80) &&(student[i].average <= 89))
            student[i].letter_grade='B';

        else if ((student[i].average >= 70) && (student[i].average <= 79))
            student[i].letter_grade='C';

        else if ((student[i].average >= 60) && (student[i].average <= 69))
            student[i].letter_grade='D';

        else if ((student[i].average >= 0) && (student[i].average <= 59))
            student[i].letter_grade='F'; }
}

void displayResults(StudentRecord student[], int number_of_students)
{
    cout << fixed<< setprecision(2);
    cout << "Student ID" << setw(10) << "StudentName" << setw(10) << "Answers" << setw(10) <<"Total Pts" << setw(10) << "Average" << setw(12) << "Letter Grade"<<endl;
    cout << setfill('-');
    cout << setw(50) << "-" << endl;
    cout << setfill(' ');

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++)
        cout << setw(3) << student[i].ID << setw(15) << student[i].student_name << setw(10) << student[i].answer.answer1 << student[i].answer.answer2 << student[i].answer.answer3 << student[i].answer.answer4
        << student[i].answer.answer5 << setw(9) << student[i].score << setw(10) << student[i].average << setw(13) << student[i].letter_grade << endl;

    cout <<"\n\n\nStudents admitted to graduate program: \n" << endl;
    cout << fixed<< setprecision(2);
    cout << "Student ID" << setw(10) << "StudentName" << setw(10) <<"Total Pts" << setw(10) << "Average" << setw(12) << "Letter Grade"<<endl;
    cout << setfill('-');
    cout << setw(40) << "-" << endl;
    cout << setfill(' ');

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++) 
    {
        if (student[i].letter_grade == 'A' || student[i].letter_grade == 'B') {
            cout << setw(2) << student[i].ID << setw(12) << student[i].student_name << setw(10) << student[i].score
                << setw(10) << student[i].average << setw(10) << student[i].letter_grade << endl; }
    }

    cout <<"\n\n\nStudents with Conditional Admission to Graduate Program: \n" << endl;
    cout << fixed<< setprecision(2);
    cout << "Student ID" << setw(10) << "StudentName" << setw(10) <<"Total Pts" << setw(10) << "Average" << setw(12) << "Letter Grade"<<endl;
    cout << setfill('-');
    cout << setw(40) << "-" << endl;
    cout << setfill(' ');

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++) 
    {
        if (student[i].letter_grade == 'C') {
            cout << setw(2) << student[i].ID << setw(10) << student[i].student_name << setw(10) << student[i].score
                << setw(10) << student[i].average << setw(10) << student[i].letter_grade << endl; }
    }

    cout <<"\n\n\nStudents Not Allowed Admission: \n" << endl;
    cout << fixed<< setprecision(2);
    cout << "Student ID" << setw(10) << "StudentName" << setw(10) <<"Total Pts" << setw(10) << "Average" << setw(12) << "Letter Grade"<<endl;
    cout << setfill('-');
    cout << setw(40) << "-" << endl;
    cout << setfill(' ');

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++) 
    {
        if (student[i].letter_grade == 'D' || student[i].letter_grade == 'F') {
            cout << setw(2) << student[i].ID << setw(10) << student[i].student_name << setw(10) << student[i].score
                << setw(10) << student[i].average << setw(10) << student[i].letter_grade << endl; }
    }
}

void searchIDandDisplay(StudentRecord student[], int number_of_students, int ID)
{
    bool check = true;
    string acceptence;

    cout << "\n\n\nEnter the ID of the student: ";
    cin >> ID;


    while (check) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++)
        {
            if (ID == student[i].ID) 
            {
                check = false; 
            }
        }
        if (check == true) 
        {
            cout << "No student with this ID" << endl;
            cin >> ID;
        }
    }


    int i = LinearSearch(student, number_of_students, ID, student[0].ID, student[number_of_students].ID);

    if (student[i].letter_grade == 'A' || student[i].letter_grade == 'B' || student[i].letter_grade == 'C') {
        acceptence = "Accepted"; }
    else
        acceptence = "Denied";


    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Student ID" << setw(10)
         << "StudentName"
         << setw(10) << setw(10)
         <<"Total Pts" << setw(10)
         << "Average" << setw(10)
         << "Letter Grade"
         << "Status" << endl;
    cout << setfill('-');
    cout << setw(48) << "-" << endl;
    cout << setfill(' ');

    cout << setw(2)  << student[i].ID
         << setw(10) << student[i].student_name
         << setw(10) << student[i].score
         << setw(10) << student[i].average
         << setw(10) << student[i].letter_grade
         << setw(10) << acceptence <<endl;

}
```

Like I said a real beginner so any help will be greatly appreciated, and hope I posted right, sorry if anything wrong. And again thanks guys for any help!

Comment: Try passing as  
getInformation(&student,number_of_students);

Comment: I recommend using std::vector for that case. It's much easier to get that right.

Answer (score 0):

void getInformation(StudentRecord *student[], int& num_std);

This says `getInformation` takes an array of pointers to StudentRecord. You want just

void getInformation(StudentRecord student[], int& num_std);

which takes an array of StudentRecords.

Answer (score 0):

```
void getInformation(StudentRecord *student[], int& num_std);
```

In this declaration, `student` is taken as a pointer to pointer to `StudentRecord`. Change it to:

```
void getInformation(StudentRecord *student, int& num_std);
```

or

```
void getInformation(StudentRecord student[], int& num_std);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line

```
getInformation(student,number_of_students);
```

The type of `student` here is a `StudentRecord[]` but the parameter of `getInforamtion` is typed to `StudentRecord[]*`.  In order to make the types line up you need to change the type of the parameter to `StudentRecord*` or pass the address of `student`.

Given that you are passing the size along with the set of values I would favor changing the signature of `getInformation` to

```
void getInformation(StudentRecord *student, int& num_std);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some comments

---

```
int search;
int ID = 0;
bool check = false;
char repeat = 'y';

const int MAX_STUDENTS = 5;
int number_of_students = 0;
char key[5];

do {
    cout << "How many students: ";
    cin >> number_of_students;
```

you should check `if (number_of_students < MAX_STUDENTS)` before continuing

your array key has dimension 5 but in your for loop you go from 0..5 which is six, better still give the dimension as an argument to the function `enterKey(char *key, int maxsize) { ... }`

```
void enterKey(char key[5]) -> (char* key, int maxsize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)  -> for (int i=0; i<maxsize; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the answer to question " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> key[i]; 
    }
}
```

the formal argument specifies an array of StudentRecord *pointers*

```
void getInformation(StudentRecord *student[],int number_of_students)
```

but you do not supply that in this way:

```
StudentRecord student[MAX_STUDENTS];
enterKey(key);
getInformation(student,number_of_students);
```

if you write as above then `student` is an array of StudentRecords

instead you should change the prototype to look like this (remember array decays to ptr):

```
void getInformation(StudentRecord *student,int number_of_students)
```

another tip

your struct  Answers has 5 answer characters answer1,answer2,.. it would be more convenient to have it as an array, then you could shorten down the way you input the answers

Answer (score 0):

Your prototypes don't need names for their arguments. They just need the data types.

```
void getInformation(StudentRecord*, int&);
void enterKey(char[]);
void calculateAvgAndLetter(StudentRecord*, int, char[]);
void sortRecordsByName(StudentRecord*, int);
void displayResults(StudentRecord*, int);
bool displayReport(StudentRecord*, int);
void searchID(StudentRecord*, int);
```

Your prototype for getInformation:

```
void getInformation(StudentRecord *student[], int& num_std);
```

has its second parameter typed as int&, whereas your definition:

```
void getInformation(StudentRecord *student[],int number_of_students)
```

is missing the &. In this case, you could either remove the & from the prototype or add it to the definition and your current implementation should work the same.

And as others have said, you're overstating the first parameter. Try Removing either the [] or the * (arrays are always passed by reference anyway).